# How to pass data in template ng-dialog?

Tags: angularjs

I tried to do this as:

```
var data = [];
    ngDialog.open({ id: 'fromAService', template: 'firstDialogId', controller: 'PrototypeController', data : data});
```

In template I tried to get:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="firstDialogId">
      <div class="ngdialog-message">
         <h3>Error</h3>

            $$data$$

         <p><button class="inline btn btn-success close-this-dialog" ng-click="closeThisDialog()">Close</button></p>
      </div>
   </script>
```

It shows empty object `{}`

Comment: use `templateUrl` instead of `template`

Comment: What do you want as result ? write it

Comment: addtionally u can use scope property in ngDialog {scope: $scope} by this key and value u able to access all parent scope variables and functions in the ngDialog template.

Comment: You have associated controller - `controller: 'PrototypeController'`. Why can't you retrieve this data inside of this controller? You can also pass a scope objects as described [here](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#user-content-scope-object).

Answer (score 3):

The data you pass to the `data` property is then available under `$scope.ngDialogData`. Look at the example below.

**Open ngDialog**

```js
ngDialog.open({
    // your dialog configuration
    data: {
        myProperty: 'test'
    }
});
```

**ngDialog Template**

```
<div class="ngdialog-message">
    <h3>Error</h3>
    {{ ngDialogData.myProperty }}
    <p><button class="inline btn btn-success close-this-dialog" ng-click="closeThisDialog()">Close</button></p>
</div>
```

For more details, please refer to the [Official Documentation](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#data-string--object--array).